# CollectRates check all radio buttons

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, extensions, shipping

I am making a **shipping extension**. All the things works great but one thing no.

My **collectRates** function who is responsible to show all **shipping methods** on the **frontend** is checking all.

Code:

```
/**
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return bool|Result
 */
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    // $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */

    $listaObjetosFrete = array();
    $listaObjetosFrete = $this->obterListaObjetosFrete($request)->data;


    foreach($listaObjetosFrete as $objetoFrete){

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);

        $method->setMethodTitle($objetoFrete->descricao);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($objetoFrete->descricao);

        $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($objetoFrete->preco);

        $method->setPrice($objetoFrete->preco);
        $method->setCost($objetoFrete->preco);

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Checkout page** who shows all **shipping methods:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved

The code was the same..

```
$method->setMethod($objetoFrete->descricao);
$method->setCarrier($this->_code);
```